# Programmatically Call REST URL

Tags: jboss, resteasy, jboss6.x

**Summary**

Is there a way to programmatically call REST URLs setup in JBoss via RESTEasy so that the programmatic method call actually drills down through the REST processor to find/execute the correct endpoint?

**Background**

We have an application that has ~20 different REST endpoints and we have set the application up to receive data from other federated peers. To cut down on cross network HTML requests, the peer site sends a bulk of requests to the server, and the receiving server needs to act upon the URL it receives. Example data flow:

Server B --> [Bulk of requests sent via HTTP/Post] --> Server A breaks list down to individual URLs --> [Begin Processing]

The individual URLs are REST URLs that the receiving server is familiar with.

**Possible Solutions**

1. Have the receiving server read through the URLs it receives, and call the management beans directly

   - The downside here is that we have to write additional processing code to decode the URL strings that are received.
   - The upside to this approach is that there is no ambiguity as to what happens
2. Have the receiving server execute the URL on itself

   - The receiving server could reform the URL to be `http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/...`, and make a HTTP request on itself.
   - The downside here is that the receiving server could have to make a lot of HTTP requests upon itself (it's already somewhat busy processing "real" requests from the outside world)
3. *Preferred:* Have the receiving server access the main RESTEasy bean somehow and feed it the request.

   - Sort of combo of 1 & 2, without the manual processing of 1 or the HTTP requests involved with 2.

**Technology Stack**

- JBoss 6.0.0 AS (2010 release) / Java 6
- RESTEasy

Comment: Please take a step back and specify the big picture of what you are trying to do. Trying to batch up URLs is not restful. (especially if it turns GET operations into POST operations.) Let's say you need to query multiple users. Instead, make a restful "query batch" endpoint where you GET /users/1,2,3 or something.

Comment: I simplified the problem slightly to make it easier to understand without needing to provide code. The operations cannot be batched together in a single REST URL. I'm also not in a position to change that portion of the code, just the way it is processed on the backside.